# Set role for database connection in java (spring boot with multitenancy)

Tags: postgresql, role, multi-tenant

For every http request there is tenant identifier based on which the schema is switched (datasource switching).

```
connection.setSchema(tenantIdentifier);
```

Now to secure the data access I am introducing role per schema using below code in my method getConnection ()

```
connection.createStatement().execute("SET ROLE " + role);
```

Is there any other alternative way/recommended way to set the role ?

Comment: What's wrong with `execute("SET ROLE " + role)`? Why are you looking for an alternative?

Comment: Same reason as I did not use setting up schema using postgres command, I used method given in java dependency. In case I use a different DB other than postgres and the command changes then it will be taken care by the java dependency and there will be no change in my code.